# QEMU-KVM: what does "qemu+ssh" mean?

Tags: ssh, kvm, qemu

I see instruction for migration like:

`virsh migrate web1 qemu+ssh://desthost/system`

What does the keyword `qemu+ssh://desthost/system` mean?

I suppose it means SSH to desthost for authentication purpose? What user does it use? After SSH, does it execute some command at destHost?
(If it needs to execute command, how does it do with `qemu+tls`?)

Also, does the `system` keyword has any special meaning too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: `qemu+ssh://desthost/system` mean run command (`migrate` in your case) using *qemu driver* on system *libvirt daemon* which is running on remote host `desthost`. For connection, use *SSH* with my current settings.

---

The *"keyword"* `qemu+ssh://desthost/system` you are mentioning is in fact called *Remote URI*, which is variation of *Connection URI* which is *libvirt* using for connecting to remote hosts.

Its general form is described in [Remote URI documentation](https://libvirt.org/uri.html#URI_remote) as

```
driver[+transport]://[username@][hostname][:port]/[path][?extraparameters]
```

> What does the keyword `qemu+ssh://desthost/system` mean?

It means that you want to execute command

1. using `qemu` driver
2. on `desthost` host
3. connecting through ordinary SSH connection
4. connect to libvirt's `system` mode daemon

> After SSH, does it execute some command at destHost? (If it needs to execute command, how does it do with qemu+tls?)

First of all you are using *virsh* to execute command `migrate` on remote host's *libvirt daemon*. That daemon will handle your command.

Think of *SSH* usage in this case only as a tunnel.

> I suppose it means SSH to desthost for authentication purpose? What user does it use? After SSH, does it execute some command at destHost? (If it needs to execute command, how does it do with qemu+tls?)

`ssh` is only transport for actual communication. Its useful especially if you have working SSH connection to remote host (`desthost`) as you avoid need to setup TLS certificates on your machine (*client*) and `desthost`.

It uses same user as actual `ssh` would use - usually current user. But you take advantage of all *SSH* possibilities and set different user i.e. in `.ssh/config` for `desthost`.

> Also, does the `system` keyword has any special meaning too?

Yes, it means that *system* mode of *libvirt daemon* will be used. With some simplification, it means it will connect to system *libvirt daemon* which is running under *root* user and usually launched at system startup. You can read more about difference between `system` and `session` in [libvirt's FAQ](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_qemu:.2F.2F.2Fsystem_and_qemu:.2F.2F.2Fsession.3F_Which_one_should_I_use.3F)